# Why is one root extraneous when using complex number polynomial expansions of cos(4x) to find cos(π/8)?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Using De Moivre's theorem, binomial expansion, and the Pythagorean identity, I have the following polynomial for $\cos 4\theta$:

$$\cos\left(4\theta\right) = 8\cos^4\theta -8\cos^2\theta +1 $$

I trying to find an exact value for $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)$.

Since $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=0$, then $\cos\left(4\cdot\frac{\pi}{8}\right)=0$, so it must be true that
$$ 8\cos^4\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right) -8\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right) +1 =0$$
and by the quadratic formula I have
$$ \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right) = \pm\frac{\sqrt{2\pm\sqrt{2}}}{2} $$
Since $\frac{\pi}{8}$ is in the first quadrant, we discard the negative root, so we have
$$  \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{2\pm\sqrt{2}}}{2} $$

Now, $  \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{2} $ is true, but  $  \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}{2} $ is false. (I know this from the approximate numerical value of $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)$.)

**My question:** How do we know $\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}{2}$ is an extraneous root?

Comment: In addition to the answers posted, we also know from the "cosine half-angle formula" , $$ \cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2} \right) \ \ = \ \ \pm \sqrt{\frac{1 \ + \ \cos \theta}{2}}\ \ , $$ that since $ \ \frac{\pi}{4} \ $ and so $ \ \frac{\pi}{8} \ $ are in the first quadrant, we _should_ have $$ \cos \left(\frac{\pi / 4}{2} \right) \ \ = \ \  \sqrt{\frac{1 \ + \ \cos  (\pi/4)}{2}} \ \ = \ \  \sqrt{\frac{1 \ + \ ( \ \sqrt2 \  / \ 2 \ )}{2}} \ \ = \ \ \sqrt{\frac{2 \ \large{+} \  \normalsize{ \sqrt2 } }{4}} \ \ . $$

Answer (score 3):

Since $0<\frac\pi8<\frac\pi4$, and since $\cos|_{[0,\pi/2]}$ is strictly decreasing,$$1>\cos\left(\frac\pi8\right)>\cos\left(\frac\pi4\right)=\frac{\sqrt2}2.$$But$$\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}}2<\frac{\sqrt2}2.$$

Comment: Ah yes. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Note that by setting $\theta=\frac{3\pi}{8},\frac{9\pi}{8}, \frac{11\pi}{8}$ we recover three more solutions to the very same quartic equation. Since this equation can only have 4 solutions, this is the complete set of solutions.

Now $\cos\frac{9\pi}{8}=-\cos\frac{\pi}{8}$ and $\cos\frac{11\pi}{8}=-\cos\frac{3\pi}{8}$ and therefore, of the positive roots one of them is $\cos\pi/8$ and the other is $\cos 3\pi/8.$ Since $\cos x$ ia s decreasing function in $[0,\pi]$, conclude that the desired value must be the lowest of the two positive ones, and get $\cos 3\pi/8$ for free as well.